How to have font-size shrink according to screen size?
I'm trying to get to grips with HTML and CSS. I have a pre tag whose text is dependent on a form input. The user types in text and it posts to another page where the text is displayed. I use the pre tag because the text can include whitespace.
All I'm looking to achieve is, if the text is so long that it's beyond the size of the screen (requiring a scroll bar), I want to shrink it down so it doesn't require a scroll bar. I've tried all kinds of font-sizes, size-adjust, 1vw, 1em, etc. but nothing is working.
Is this even possible? Or am I going about solving this the complete wrong way? I am not looking to wrap the text. Thanks.
Example of what I've tried so far:
body {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

pre {
    font-size: 1vw;
}

I tried setting the font-size to 1vw and calc(1vw + 1vh) and using various percentages, expecting the font to shrink to fit the size of the screen, but it still breaks the edge.

You need a javascript for that. Not sure if it is an option for you.
